# There is no output by TeXnicCenter

Tags: tikz-pgf

I recently encountered a problem when drawing my graphs with gnuplot. When I run my TeX file in TeXnicCenter, it runs but the output PDF file is not relating to the requested file!

By running the other files the output is the same and TeXnicCenter makes no change to the graphs and shows the initial PDF graph which seems to be in its memory!

I would be grateful if someone could help me about this problem.

Comment: this usually happens whhen you have a fatal error that stops the compilation before the file changes. so you see the same file. do you see 0 errors 0 pages in the log windiw by any chance? texniccenter has no memory.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It would be helpful to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.